# Задание кнопки в Xcode кодом

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Во время написания приложения возникла нужда задать кнопку программным способом. Все хорошо, но не получаются некоторые вещи:

1) При нажатии кнопки нет никаких визуальных эффектов, как если делать через IB (видимо как то отдельно надо прописывать это)

2) Не удается установить свое изображение на кнопку (ни по стандарту, ни при нажатии)

Хедер файл:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIButton *button1;

-(IBAction)btn1:(id)sender;
```

Реализация:

```
@synthesize button1;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(327, 16, 32, 32)];

  button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn1:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[scrollView addSubview:button1];
}

-(IBAction)btn1:(id)sender {
    UIImage *checkSel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
  [self.button1 setBackgroundImage:checkSel forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

Видимо у меня property не связано с самой кнопкой? 
Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: ну метод должен отрабатывать , проверьте состояния для которого задается картинка,  UIControlStateSelected - кнопка нажата, и зачем вам retain и @synthesize вы же наверняка используете ARC

Comment: Я думал synthesize всегда нужно для property

Comment: https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/265175/ , вот можно почитать, для начала будет достаточно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так 
хедер:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *button1;

- (void)btn1Tap:(UIButton *)sender;
```

мейн:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _button1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(327, 16, 32, 32)];
    _button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [_button1 addTarget:self 
                 action:@selector(btn1:) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [scrollView addSubview:button1];
}

- (void)btn1Tap:(UIButton *)sender {
     UIImage *checkSel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
     [sender setBackgroundImage:checkSel forState:UIControlStateSelected]; 
     [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; 
}
```